# Definition of $0^\underline{m}$ for $m\leq0$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Using the general definition of falling powers for negative exponents, I was able to derive
$$0^{\underline{m}} = \frac{1}{(-m)!}, m\leq0$$
However, I can't reconcile this with the product formula
$$0^\underline{m+n} = 0^\underline{m}0^\underline{n}$$
which the book puts no restrictions on in terms of the base, since if one takes $m=m, n=-m$, one gets
$$1=0\frac{1}{0!}$$
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: These are falling powers

Comment: @thomasandrews sorry, that was to another person who hadn't seen the m<0. The book is concrete math, chapter 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is

$$x^{\underline{m+n}}=x^{\underline m}(x-m)^{\underline n}\;;$$

when $x=0$ you have

$$0^{\underline{m+n}}=0^{\underline m}(-m)^{\underline n}\;.$$

For negative $m$ and $n=-m$ this becomes

$$0^{\underline 0}=0^{\underline m}(-m)^{\underline{-m}}=\frac1{(0+1)^{\overline{-m}}}\cdot(-m)!=1\;,$$

which is fine.

There is a small problem for positive $m$ and $n=-m$: it becomes

$$0^{\underline 0}=0^{\underline m}(-m)^{\underline{-m}}=0\cdot\frac1{(-m+1)^{\overline m}}=0\cdot\frac10\;,$$

which is indeed problematic. One simply has to avoid this situation (or agree that in this one exceptional situation one can cancel the $0$s).

Comment: Of course, I misremembered the formula! Thank you.

Comment: @René: You’re welcome.